# how to save authentication state using android viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am currently building an app where i use JWT authentication on backend side. So whenever user logins or signs up then new access token is created. I save that token( and userid) inside `SharedPreferences`

So in the app depending on the feature there things that user should login to use. User can also use some features without logging in.

That is why, when user clicks features that requires authentication,i want to check if there is data inside shared preferences.Basically if there is not data, then user did not sign in and it returns `false`

```
fun isAuthenticated():Boolean {
    val user = sharedPreferencesRepository.getUser()
    return user.userId != null && user.token != null
}
```

But i think it is not effective way of doing that, because each time i should get the data from shared preferences.I want to get only once and reuse it when i need it

Comment: There is no problem with requesting data from shared preference many times. It is optimized for this kind of use cases. After first request, the data is kept in memory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create something that represents a session and store it for the time your application is alive (including its updates on log in  / log out).

1. You create a Session class (or whatever name you prefer) that is attached to your application scope. If you use dependency injection (i.e. Dagger2 / Hilt or Koin) it's basically a singleton.
2. Your DI should create this instance at the start of your application by obtaining value from shared prefs if such exists.
3. This instance could be wrapped around some sort of repository (authentication manager, use case etc.) and provided (or its wrapper, depending on your architecture) to any class that needs this info - usually view model.
4. Actions such as log in / log out should not only update shared pref but also should trigger session update.